# Calculate consecutive holiday/weekend in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope someone can help me with this. I put the simple example below:
For billing purpose I need to skip holidays and weekend to set the right due date for a billing date.
I have a holiday table which hold all the holidays for the company (and may contain some weekend such Saturday--not quite sure now as some company such as bank, we can not consider the special case for now).

I need to find out the consecutive holidays in the database Plus consecutive weekend.

For holiday data in the database for example:

```
 EXCP_DATE ID 
 ----------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- 
 3/29/2013 1 
 4/1/2013 1 
 12/9/2013 1 
 12/10/2013 1 
 12/25/2013 1 
 12/26/2013 1 
 12/27/2013 1 
 12/28/2013 1
```

I need the number of holidays and weekend under "occurences" column. consecutive holidays/weekend
my CONSECUTIVE_DAY: 1 means the date has consecutive holiday/weekend

```
 ID EXCP_DATE WeekDay CONSECUTIVE_DAY OCCURENCES
 1 3/29/2013 FRIDAY 1 3 
 2 4/1/2013 MONDAY 0 1 
 3 12/9/2013 MONDAY 1 2 
 4 12/10/2013 TUESDAY 0 1 
 5 12/25/2013 WEDNESDAY 1 5 
 6 12/26/2013 THURSDAY 1 4 
 7 12/27/2013 FRIDAY 1 3 
 8 12/28/2013 SATURDAY 1 2
```

Below is the query which works for most cases. It only fails when there is more than 2 consecutive holidays as it only lead one step.

```
SELECT A.*
    ,CASE 
        WHEN CONSECUTIVE_DAY = 1
            THEN CASE 
                    WHEN upper(datename(weekday, EXCP_DATE)) = 'FRIDAY'
                        AND LEAD(EXCP_DATE) OVER (
                            ORDER BY EXCP_DATE
                            ) = (EXCP_DATE + 3)
                        THEN DATEdiff(dd, EXCP_DATE, LEAD(EXCP_DATE) OVER (
                                    ORDER BY EXCP_DATE
                                    )) + 1
                    WHEN upper(datename(weekday, EXCP_DATE)) = 'FRIDAY'
                        AND LEAD(EXCP_DATE) OVER (
                            ORDER BY EXCP_DATE
                            ) <> (EXCP_DATE + 3)
                        THEN 3
                    ELSE DATEdiff(dd, EXCP_DATE, LEAD(EXCP_DATE) OVER (
                                ORDER BY EXCP_DATE
                                )) + 1
                    END
        ELSE CONSECUTIVE_DAY
        END OCCURENCES
FROM (
    SELECT T.*
        ,upper(datename(weekday, EXCP_DATE)) WeekDay
        ,Lead(EXCP_DATE, 1, EXCP_DATE) OVER (
            ORDER BY EXCP_DATE
            ) Lead
        ,EXCP_DATE + 1 [EXCP_DATE + 1]
        ,EXCP_DATE + 3 [EXCP_DATE +3]
        ,datename(weekday, EXCP_DATE + 3) [DateName_EXCP_DATE +3]
        ,
        ---------------------------
        CASE 
            WHEN Lead(EXCP_DATE, 1, EXCP_DATE) OVER (
                    ORDER BY EXCP_DATE
                    ) = EXCP_DATE + 1
                THEN 1
            WHEN upper(datename(weekday, EXCP_DATE)) = 'FRIDAY'
                AND LEAD(EXCP_DATE) OVER (
                    ORDER BY EXCP_DATE
                    ) = EXCP_DATE + 3
                THEN 1
            WHEN upper(datename(weekday, EXCP_DATE)) = 'SATURDAY'
                AND LEAD(EXCP_DATE) OVER (
                    ORDER BY EXCP_DATE
                    ) = EXCP_DATE + 2
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END CONSECUTIVE_DAY
    FROM TEST1 T
    ) A
```

-----------------------------------The number 5 and 6 are not correct. How can I do recursive on Lead?

The result:

```
 ID EXCP_DATE WeekDay Lead EXCP_DATE + 1 EXCP_DATE +3 DateName_EXCP_DATE +3 CONSECUTIVE_DAY OCCURENCES
 1 3/29/2013 FRIDAY 4/1/2013 3/30/2013 4/1/2013 Monday 1 4
 2 4/1/2013 MONDAY 12/9/2013 4/2/2013 4/4/2013 Thursday 0 0
 3 12/9/2013 MONDAY 12/10/2013 12/10/2013 12/12/2013 Thursday 1 2
 4 12/10/2013 TUESDAY 12/25/2013 12/11/2013 12/13/2013 Friday 0 0
 5 12/25/2013 WEDNESDAY 12/26/2013 12/26/2013 12/28/2013 Saturday 1 2
 6 12/26/2013 THURSDAY 12/27/2013 12/27/2013 12/29/2013 Sunday 1 2
 8 12/27/2013 FRIDAY 12/28/2013 12/28/2013 12/30/2013 Monday 1 3
 7 12/28/2013 SATURDAY 12/28/2013 12/29/2013 12/31/2013 Tuesday 0 0
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to read and understand this? Please format the post appropriately.

Comment: I added the sql-server tag because the code looks like SQL Server (and version 2012+ at that).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different approach. Create a function that just returns the next valid business date when provided a starting date.

For example, lets say someone's due date is calculated 5/24/2014 (which is a Saturday). You can pass that value into a function to return the next valid business date. Here is a quick function that I wrote to do this.

This function assumes you have a table called [Holidays] that contains the dates of the holidays for your company.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NextBusinessDay]
(
    @BusinessDay DATE
)
RETURNS DATE AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @GoodDay DATE;
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT @BusinessDay AS good_date
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateAdd(d,1,good_date)
        FROM CTE 
        WHERE good_date < DateAdd(d,7,@BusinessDay)
    )
    SELECT @GoodDay = min(good_date) FROM cte
    WHERE Upper(DateName(WEEKDAY, good_date)) NOT IN ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Holiday] FROM [Holidays] WHERE [Holiday] = good_date);
    RETURN @GoodDay;
END;
```

Then you would just pass in the dates.

```
SELECT DueDate, [dbo].[NextBusinessDay](DueDate) FROM Whatever
```

In the example above, this would return 5/27/2014, since 5/24/2014 and 5/25/2014 are weekends, and 5/26/2014 is a holiday (if you have Memorial Day in your Holidays table).